# kableExtra addfootnote general spanning multiple lines with PDF (LaTeX) output

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kable, kableextra

### Problem

#### Code

```
# Toy Data
ID <- c(paste("G0", as.character(1:9), sep = ""),"G10","G11","Mean")
V1 <- c(10.06,11.06,12.06,13.06,14.06,15.06,16.06,17.07,18.07,19.07,6.88,13.86)
V2 <- c(0.21,0.03,0.09,0.03,0.09,0.03,0.09,0.03,0.09,0.21,0.31,NA)
tbl <- data.frame(ID, V1, V1, V2, V1, V2, V1, V2, V2)
colnames(tbl) <- c('ID','Get. \\%','Get. \\%','K','Get. \\%','K','Get. \\%','K','P')

# Specify kable NA value and load kableExtra
options(knitr.kable.NA = '--')
require(kableExtra)

# Generate table for PDF output (LaTeX)
kbl(tbl, format = 'latex', align = 'l', booktabs = T, escape = F, digits = 2,
    linesep = "", caption = "This is a table caption.") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "AB", "BP" = 2, "CK" = 2, "JAM" = 2, ""), bold = T) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = '1.15cm') %>%
  row_spec(11, hline_after = T) %>%
  row_spec(12, bold = T) %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center", latex_options = "hold_position") %>%
  footnote(general_title = "Note.", footnote_as_chunk = T, 
           general = "Relatively long footnote that I would like to span 
                     a couple of lines. Relatively long footnote that I
                     would like to span a couple of lines.")
```

#### Output

[image]

### Comments

**Issue 1:** The output displays 'makecell[1]' in the footnote, which I obviously do not want included. Adding the argument `escape = T` did not resolve this problem as I expected it might have.

**N.B.** By setting `footnote_as_chunk = F`, this issue was resolved, but with the unwanted effect of introducing a line break before the caption starts. This is demonstrated by Peter's answer below.

**Issue 2** The footnote does not want to be constrained to the length of the table. I suppose one might be able to manually add line breaks in the footnote string, but this seems like tedious work-around, and I'm hoping there is a method for achieving this more efficiently. The [documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) *shows* (see Table 4, p. 25) an example of how one might circumvent this problem, but the code is absent.

**EDIT:** This issue (#2) was resolved by setting `threeparttable = T` when calling `kbl`.

Compiling with pdflatex or xelatex does not seem to make any difference. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no `'makecell[1]'` in your code. What is it that you want to display instead of `'makecell[1]'` ?

Comment: This appears in the output @RonakShah (i.e. see the image). As mentioned by my update, I was ultimately able to resolve this, and the fix is described in my updated Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)

kbl(tbl, 
    format = 'latex',
    longtable = TRUE,
    align = 'l', 
    booktabs = T, 
    escape = F, 
    digits = 2,
    linesep = "", 
    caption = "This is a table caption.") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "AB", "BP" = 2, "CK" = 2, "JAM" = 2, ""), bold = T) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = '1.15cm') %>%
  row_spec(11, hline_after = T) %>%
  row_spec(12, bold = T) %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center", latex_options = "hold_position", full_width = FALSE) %>%
  footnote(general_title = "Note.", 
           footnote_as_chunk = TRUE,
           threeparttable = TRUE,
           general = "Relatively long footnote that I would like to span a couple of lines. Relatively long footnote that I would like to span a couple of lines.")
```

With `footnote_as_chunk = TRUE` using the "general" footnote option "Note." and the "Footnote...." text start on the same line. As in this example, image below.

[image]

Comment: Helpful, and was the first step toward tackling the issue. Given aesthetic preferences, I wanted `footnote_as_chunk = T`. I ultimately edited the TEX file to get my desired output, but I wonder if there is a fix using just kable/kableExtra?

Comment: I've just rerun the code in the answer with with `footnote_as_chunk = T`. And it gives the same result. I've updated the code.

Comment: to clarify, do you get the output with the `general` string beginning on the same line as the string passed to `general_title` (i.e. Note.)? My understanding is that this is the behaviour that `footnote_as_chunk = T` accomplishes, which you can see from my original post, i.e. the `general` string starts on the same line as 'Note.'

Comment: @Speleo4Life I've just updated the answer following your clarification - which is really helpful - I'd missed the subtle difference. You are correct setting `footnote_as_chunk = TRUE` puts "Note." and the "Footnote.... text" on the same line i.e. in the same text chuck. Makes sense.